# Capturing data packets in closed LAN

Tags: networking, wireshark, lan, packet-capture

In my college lab, all the PCs are connected via a hub. I want to capture data packets using Wireshark, but it only displays the interface of my own PC. How can I capture the packets of other PCs?

I've tried all the interfaces, and I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Odds are you're connected to a switch rather than a hub. The problem there is that only packets intended for your network card's hardware (MAC) address and broadcast packets will be sent to your PC. The switch remembers the hardware address of devices plugged into it and performs packet forwarding based on those addresses. This vastly increases the potential bandwidth of your network segment, but makes snooping on other traffic more difficult. You will need to perform what's called ARP cache poisoning. Basically you need to trick every other computer connected to the switch to send its traffic to you rather than its true destination. You will then need to forward those packets not actually for you onto the correct destination otherwise it will take down the entire segment you're on and people will get nosy.

This type of redirection is possible, but it seems like you'll need to do quite a bit more research and understand exactly what is going on before attempting it. To get started, look into the Address Resolution Protocol; understand what a "layer 2" switch is doing; find out how to inject and reroute packets on the network; think about the consequences of getting caught.

If you're serious about moving forward, check out http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Arp-Cache-Poisoning-and-Packet-Sniffing for some starting tips.